# Css horizontally center wider child in narrow parent

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I could horizontally center child (to parent) which is wider than a absolute positoned parent wihhout knowing child width?  I dont need to have white-space:nowrap on child, but I need at least some width on child like max-width 200px;  Only css, not javascript.

```css
.p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  left: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.c {
  white-space: nowrap;
    /*max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;/
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `.p` a flexbox and `absolute`-ly position `.c`:

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  
  outline: 2px solid red; /* So that we know where it is */
  
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  
  background: red;
}

#p1 {
  left: 100px;
}

#p2 {
  left: 300px;
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

#c1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#c2 {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p" id="p1">
  <div class="c" id="c1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="p" id="p2">
  <div class="c" id="c2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could this work with max-width instead of nowrap?

Comment: @Toniq I updated the snippet. You can see it for yourself.